# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'anomalib.engine'

Tags: python, machine-learning, anomaly-detection, openvino

```
# Import the required modules

from anomalib.data import MVTec
from anomalib.models import Patchcore
from anomalib.engine import Engine
```

error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'anomalib.engine'
```

I'm trying to run this.... have followed the library installation and seen the
https://anomalib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/markdown/get_started/anomalib.html
I think its either becuase the engine has been modified or it has been dropped by the library...

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem.
That document is probably for ver 1.0.0, but currently pip installs ver 0.7.0 instead of 1.0.0.

So I tried a following installation code and ModuleNotFoundError disappear in my Google Colab environment.

```
!git clone https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/anomalib.git
%cd anomalib
%pip install .
```

FYI
However, even after passing this error, the error `No module named 'openvino.tools.mo'` occurred in openvino installed with pip.

It could be fixed by installing openvino-dev as listed in the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/anomalib/blob/main/requirements/openvino.txt).

```
%pip install openvino-dev==2023.0
```